what movie/show has a cave fight scene
All I really remember is there were hooks on the ceiling and they had gravity boots and they were fighting upside down. I want to say the movie had vampires or elves?
It was a newer (last 10-15 years) movie, english mainstream type of thing. I don't remember the genre, but it has its action moments and its smart a$$ one liners. I think the protagonist was a somewhat unlikely hero, and I think maybe they infiltrate this cave of bad guys, but they're ill prepared, as they don't have the fancy boots with hooks on them. I think the guys defending their lair have curved blades, and at one point someone is hanging precariously from the rings on the ceilings that serve as foot holds. I'm pretty sure they end up getting captured.
I'm not certain, but I think they infiltrate the cave by stealing/stowing away/riding a ship/animal that the "bad guys" use as transportation. That's why they were unprepared for the lack of floors when they get there.

Going to need quite a bit more detail to help answer this. Was it old, new, color, in english, was it scifi or fantasy, who were the main characters?

It was a newer (last 10-15 years) movie, and I don't remember the genre, but it has its action moments and its smart a$$ one liners. I think the protagonist was a somewhat unlikely hero, and I think maybe they infiltrate this cave of bad guys, but they're ill prepared, as they don't have the fancy boots with hooks on them. I think the guys defending their lair have curved blades, and at one point someone is hanging precariously from the rings on the ceilings that serve as foot holds. I'm pretty sure they end up getting captured.

I think it was the TV movie "The Colour Of Magic" based on the book by Terry Pratchett.  
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1079959/
It's a two part series.  I think the bit you are talking about is in the first part.  It's when Twoflower and Rincewind visit the Wyrmberg.  They get there by dragon.  Then they fight the Wyrmbergs Chief daughter upside down on the ceiling, and escape using dragons.
There is a screenshot of it here on the Wiki page
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terry_Pratchett%27s_The_Colour_of_Magic
Can't find a youtube clip of the fight scene, and the DVD is no longer available.  Can't even find any decent screenshots apart from the Wikipedia one.
